# Get current position of cursor in ckeditor 5 in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm using ckeditor 5 in angular

```
    export class AppComponent {
      public editor: any;
      public html: string;
      @ViewChild('myckeditor') public myckeditor: any;
      constructor() {
        this.editor = DecoupledEditor;
        this.html = "";
      }
      public onReady(editor:any) {
        editor.plugins.get("FileRepository").createUploadAdapter = (loader:any) => {
          let file =   new MyUploadAdapter(loader);
         ..
         
 editor.ui
      .getEditableElement()
      .parentElement.insertBefore(
        editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
        editor.ui.getEditableElement()
      );

    <ckeditor
      (ready)="onReady($event)" (blur)="ckEditorFocusOut($event)"
      [editor]="editor"
      [(ngModel)]="html" #myckeditor 
    ></ckeditor>
```

i want to get the current position of cursor while user clicks on ckeditor or drag and drop items in ckeditor.

Any solution. Thanks